# MySQL: получить наибольше значение из каждой группы

Tags: mysql, sql, join

**Тестовая структура:**

```
CREATE TABLE b (
  id   INT,
  data TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE s (
  id   INT,
  b_id INT,
  time INT
);

INSERT INTO b VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO b VALUES (2, 3);

INSERT INTO s VALUES (1, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO s VALUES (2, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO s VALUES (3, 1, 9);
INSERT INTO s VALUES (4, 2, 8);
INSERT INTO s VALUES (5, 2, 4);
INSERT INTO s VALUES (6, 2, 5);
```

**Задача:**

В один запрос, для каждого `id` из `b` получить из `s` значение с *максимальным* значением поля `time`

**Ожидаемый вывод здесь:**

```
+------+------+------+------+-----------+
| id   | data | b_id | sid  |    time   |
+------+------+------+------+-----------+
|    1 | 2    |    1 |    3 |         9 |
|    2 | 3    |    2 |    4 |         8 |
+------+------+------+------+-----------+
```

(имена столбцов не существенны. Пример приведен для упрощения понимая задачи)

**Чего смог сам(ну, я пытался)**

```
select b.id as bid, b.data, s.time, s.b_id from b b inner join s s on b.id=s.b_id order by s.time DESC;
+------+------+------+------+
| bid  | data | time | b_id |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 | 2    |    9 |    1 |
|    2 | 3    |    8 |    2 |
|    2 | 3    |    5 |    2 |
|    2 | 3    |    4 |    2 |
|    1 | 2    |    3 |    1 |
|    1 | 2    |    2 |    1 |
+------+------+------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**ВАЖНО** в субд ожидается включенный режим `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: У вас неполная постановка задачи. Что ожидается в случае если в таблице b есть id = 3, а в таблице s нет ни одной записи с таким id -- непонятно. И вообще, такая ситуация возможа или нет? Но уже за аккуратность в оформлении вопроса -- плюс.

Comment: @A_K, Такая ситуация невозможна. Именно поэтому и не пришла в голову мысль написать об этом. Спасибо за замечание!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT b.*, (SELECT MAX(s.`time`) 
             FROM s  
             WHERE s.`b_id` = b.`id`
            ) AS max_s_time
FROM b
```

Comment: а как в этом же запросе получить хотя бы еще `s.id`?

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko можно пойти от обратного и попробовать так `SELECT s.id AS s_id, s.\`time\`, b.id AS b_id, b.\`data\`
FROM s 
JOIN b
ON b.\`id\` = s.\`b_id\`
WHERE s.time IN (
 (SELECT MAX(s.\`time\`) AS s_time
 FROM s
 GROUP BY s.\`b_id\`
 )
)` - но это не точно.... зависит еще от того, может ли повторяться связка значений `b_id`|`time` в таблице `s` или нет. и пр

Answer (score 0):

Используйте следующее выражение:

```
SELECT 
  b.id,
  MAX(s.time) AS time
FROM
  b 
  LEFT JOIN s 
    ON b.id = s.b_id 
GROUP BY b.id
```

Comment: В этом варианте другие столбцы нельзя выбрать.